# Keeps getting error Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Just started learning CTE, followed everything in the tutorial, but I keep getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

This is the `Users` table:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
WITH BannedCTE
AS
(SELECT Users_Id
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Banned = "Yes");
```

Comment: Single quotes around a text literal?

Comment: Please add your data as text not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below query. You should use CTE with select,DML operation(Insert, update, delete). Use Single Quotes for String.

```
WITH BannedCTE AS (SELECT Users_Id FROM Users WHERE Users.Banned = 'Yes')
select * from BannedCTE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280586/keeps-getting-error-incorrect-syntax-near-102-sqlexecdirectw#58280670):

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT
>   statement of the view.

So, just try this:

```
;WITH BannedCTE AS 
(
    SELECT Users_Id 
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.Banned = 'Yes'
)
SELECT * 
FROM BannedCTE ;
```